# Unix export command path

Tags: bash, shell, unix, apache-nifi

I want to run a single line command via NiFi ExecuteStreamCommand processor. I want to run a `gsutil` command and before doing that I want to export environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.
So the command would be

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/temp/abc.json'`

However, NiFi needs the path of the command. On the server when I checked `which export` I do not get its path:

```
[user@server1 ~]$ which export
/usr/bin/which: no export in (/opt/teradata/client/14.10/tbuild/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin:/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/bin/)
```

If its a builtin command, how do I get NiFi to run it?

Comment: `export` is shell builtin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I get NiFi to run it?

Use `env` to run a command with modified environment.

```
/usr/bin/env GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/temp/abc.json' gsutil
```